# Can't use keyword arguments with overloaded functions

Tags: python, c++, vector, swig

*Note:* The corresponding gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/nschloe/2905bbd136605aa91eeb5d22cbe6ec05)

---

I'm SWIGging some C++ code to be used from Python, and I'm using `std::vector<double>` in the interface, e.g.,

`myfoo.hpp`

```
#ifndef MYFOO_HPP
#define MYFOO_HPP

#include <vector>

double sum(const std::vector<double> & a) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (const auto & elem: a) {
    sum += elem;
  }
  return sum;
}

#endif // MYFOO_HPP
```

`myfoo.i`

```
%module myfoo

%{
#include "myfoo.hpp"
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
namespace std {
%template(Line) vector<double>;
}

%include "myfoo.hpp"
```

When SWIGging with the `-keyword` option (not really necessary in this mini example), e.g.,

```
swig -python -keyword -c++ -o myfoo_wrap.cpp myfoo.i
```

I'm getting *tons* of warnings like

```
/usr/share/swig3.0/std/std_vector.i:94: Warning 511: Can't use keyword arguments with overloaded functions (std::vector< double >::erase(std::vector< double >::iterator)).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT`, you do not have an `%init` section

Comment: It is stated in documentation that SWIG is unaware of using `keyword` together with overloaded functions.

Comment: Not sure what "overloaded functions" means in this context. Link?

Comment: If you look into `std::vector` you will see it makes use of overloading. Operators which support both const and no const.

Comment: This is how I understood it but I may be wrong.

Comment: I think -keyword is basically impossible to use with any serious C++

Comment: It's not like it doesn't work, it's all fine except for the warnings. Perhaps it's possible to turn those off?

Comment: There's a nowarn pragma: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Warnings.html#Warnings_suppression but I think you still end up with broken overloads still.